# Automatically enforce Code Analysis policies in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

Our team are looking into implementing Code Analysis as a check in policy in TFS.

We've decided on which rules we want to enforce but won't be applying the policies to TFS for a while as we are currently migrating to TFS 2010.

In the meantime to get used to it and start removing Code Analysis warnings the dev team are going to start manually enabling Code Analysis.

So, is there a way we can publish or automatically enforce a set of rules without having to manually edit the properties for every project in every solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sharing Code Analysis settings between projects in VS 2008, see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/11/16/faq-how-do-i-share-managed-code-analysis-rule-settings-over-multiple-projects-david-kean.aspx.  (The article was written for VS 2005, but the same approach is appropriate in VS 2008 as well.  In VS 2010, use of a shared rule set file is a better approach, although it may be specified using the same imported target mechanism.)

Comment: Thanks. Looks fairly involved but should be quicker than editing rules for every individual project. I'll try it out.